# Can't avoid n+1 selects with many to many relationship in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'm creating a toy Q&A site with Grails in order to learn the platform.
I have two domains, Posts and Tags, with a many to many relationship between them. I want to print a list of posts with their tags.

I can't use lazy fetching, because I would run into the N+1 selects problem

I can't use eager fetching either because it uses a left join and I wouldn't be able to page the results properly.

Therefore I decided to manually fetch the tags with the following code:

```
static def getList(params) {

        ArrayList questions = Question.list(params)

        def questionMap = [:]
        questions.each {
            questionMap.put(it.id, it)
        }

        if(questions.size()>0) {
            Tag.executeQuery('SELECT q.id, t FROM Tag t JOIN t.questions q \
                                WHERE q.id in ( :list ) ', [ list:questions.collect{ it.id } ] ).each { questionMap.get(it[0]).tags.add(it[1]) }
        }

        return questions
}
```

however when I print the tags in my view:

```
<g:each in="${questions}" var="question">
   ${question.title} 
   <g:each in="${question.tags}" var="tag">
      ${tag?.text}
   </g:each>
</g:each>
```

A query is executed for each question anyway!
What is the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't do anything with the result of your `Tag` query. Also, it's a better approach to have a join class for many-to-many relationships. If you see the Spring Security Core plugin, for example, you have the `User`, the `Role` and a join class called `UserRole`. [Here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/domain/test/TestUserRole.groovy) is the example class.

So my suggestion to you is:

```
class Tag {
...
}

class Question{
...
}

class QuestionTag implements Serializable {
  Tag tag
  Question question
  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['tag','question']
    ...
  }
  //need to override equals and hashCode
}
```

To store the result of tags, you can add a transient field for your class:

class Question {
  def tags
  static transients = ['tags']
  //remove the hasMany.
}

You can now execute your `HQL`, look for the instance of question in your questions list and set the `tags` attribute. And since you are using one HQL that don't return a single class, the result is not mapped as a `Tag` object, so the access is a little different.

> HQL queries can return domain class instances, or Arrays of specified
>   data when the query selects individual fields or calculated values

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean I don't do anything with the results of my Tag query? I do add the tags to the corresponding questions' tag list, and latter print them. In a perfect world that's all I want to do with them... or am I missing something here?

Comment: You don't do nothing with the result of `Tag.executeQuery`, that's what I mean.

Comment: I do execute a closure for handling the results of the query: 
Tag.executeQuery( .... ).each { 
   questionMap.get(it[0]).tags.add(it[1])
}
right?

Comment: Ok, I missed the each. But you store this in the `questionMap` so shouldnt your method return `questionMap` instead of `question`?

Comment: Both question and questionMap contain references to the same objects. It's my fault that the code is probably not as easy to read as it shold, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

> "I can't use eager fetching either because it uses a left join and I
>   wouldn't be able to page the results properly."

You can do paging for an association by using session.createFilter.

This example (copyright Burt Beckwith) is from [Burt Beckwith's book Programming Grails](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do) from "Chapter 5, Hibernate , session.createFilter"

```
// example from Burt Beckwith's book "Programming Grails", (c) Burt Beckwith
class Branch {
    String name
    List visits
    static hasMany = [visits: Visit]

    List<Visit> getVisitsByPage(int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
        Branch.withSession { session ->
            session.createFilter(visits, '')
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .setFirstResult(pageSize * pageNumber)
                    .list()
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend buying [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do)

Comment: But that code retrieves a page of the collection (visits), not a page of Branches with the corresponding Visits as would be my case. Also you are not using eager fetching there as I say in the quoted text, so I don't really get it. Do you mean It's possible to create a similar construction to solve my problem using filters? If so, I would appreciate if you could elaborate a little more on that.

Comment: Oh yes, I misunderstood your requirement. In some complex cases when you want to optimize Hibernate you might have to manually assign the associations. The idea is to fetch all sub-items in one query and put them in a memory map and do the join manually in code. There must be some instructions about how and when to apply this type of ugly solution. I've had to use it several times to get rid of N+1 problem in some complex cases.

Comment: "I can't use eager fetching either because it uses a left join and I wouldn't be able to page the results properly.". I cannot directly remember what the problem is with this approach. Can you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: Say you want "N" Posts with their associated Tags. If you use a join, posts with more than 1 associated tags will appear on as many tuples as there are related tags. You don't know how many posts and tags are there before making the query, so you can't know how many tuples you need to retrieve "N" different Posts. Therefore, you can't set the limits to the query properly. 
Hope I explained myself ;)